# LibreOffice opening with the recovery window in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: libreoffice, 23.04

LibreOffice seems to work ok in Ubuntu 23.04 but whenever I want to open a new document, I get a recovery window claiming that the previously used documents crashed and need to be recovered (though when I was closing them, everything seemed ok). I re-installed LibreOffice but the same thing is happening with the newly installed version 7.5. It is no big deal but it is annoying. Is there a way to get rid of this?